# Why there is no way to check if current thread holds the read lock of ReentrantReadWriteLock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrent-programming

I found that the write lock of the `ReentrantReadWriteLock` provides an `isHeldByCurrentThread()` method to check whether the invoking thread holds that lock.

But there is no corresponding `isHeldByCurrentThread()` method for the read lock. Why not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the answer is in the comment of Doug  Leas that he gave for this issue: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6207928.

Doug Lea writes:

> The current design and behavior are intentional.  Read-locks are normally not defined to have a notion of ownership, so ownership cannot be tested.  … The JSR166 EG has received a few requests to optionally support per-thread read-hold tracking. Doing this would significantly increase lock overhead, so would need to be governed by an optional construction parameter. We are looking into it.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Nevertheless I expected there was some way to check if the current thread holds the read lock of ReentrantReadWriteLock.

Answer (score 3):

ReentrantReadWriteLock.getReadHoldCount() seems to do the job.

Comment: as long as your code is not doing reentrant readlocks, this will work

Comment: No it doesn't. Assume ThreadA acquired the read lock. The count is now 1. Before ThreadA releases the lock, ThreadB relies on getReadHoldCount() > 0 and enters the "protected" code. Now ThreadA a releases the lock, but ThreadB is still in the protected code. ThreadC comes into play, acquires a write lock, gets it (because reader count is zero), and updates some data. -> ThreadB sees inconsistent data.